# Is it possible to use `IF THEN` without using ELSE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need to write a query where user1 requests to display the `HealthStatus` of user2, however, before I display it, I need to ensure that `user2` trusts `user1`
I have a table `UserInfo` where each user has a `HealthStatus` and a table `Trusted` where if `ID1` and `ID2` are in the same row then `ID1` trusts `ID2`

I tried writing the following:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT ID1 FROM Trusted WHERE ID2=2010123 AND ID1=2009123))
THEN SELECT HealthStatus FROM UserInfo WHERE ID=2009123
```

Note: here `ID2` is the `ID` of the user executing the query (can get it easily, I am doing this in Java) and `ID1` is the `ID` of the user whose `HealthStatus` is requested to be disclosed.

Logic I am trying to apply:

"If there is any entry in the `Trusted` table such as the first ID is the one of the user whose HealthStatus is being requested and the second ID is the one of the user executing the query then do this"

I also tried:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT ID1 FROM Trusted WHERE ID2=2010123 AND ID1=2009123))
BEGIN
THEN SELECT HealthStatus FROM UserInfo WHERE ID=2009123
END
```

In both of these, the SQL Workbench underlines the `IF` statement and says `"IF" is not valid at this position, expected EOF, Alter, Analyze, etc..`

I haven't seen any statements with `IF` being used without `ELSE` so that **might** be it, any help in doing this query would be appreciated

Comment: IF needs an end if; see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html but note this is only possible in a stored program...

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks, just included it and the same error stayed

Comment: Are you using in a stored program? MySQL supports the IF, CASE, ITERATE, LEAVE LOOP, WHILE, and REPEAT constructs for flow control within stored programs' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-statements.html

Comment: @P.Salmon no I am not, would there be any other way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: `SELECT HealthStatus FROM UserInfo WHERE ID=2009123 AND EXISTS (SELECT ID1 FROM Trusted WHERE ID2=2010123 AND ID1=2009123)`. If EXISTS returns empty dataset (not trusted) then the query won't return rows.

Comment: @P.Salmon IF and CASE exists in 2 forms each - they can be statements which must be used in compound statement only, and they can be functions which can be used in single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```sql
SELECT HealthStatus
FROM UserInfo
WHERE ID = 2009123 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Trusted WHERE ID2 = 2010123 AND ID1 = 2009123);
```

If the exists clause above fails, the entire result set will be empty.